# Function fails to POST. Insted it sends a Get?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I can pass my parameters from a Kendo Grid bound columns, as shown below. But my Controller is treating it as GET. I cannot get he controller to treat it a [HTTPPOST]

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<myApp.Dal.SmKpr1Value>) ViewBag.kk1) 
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
                 {
                     columns.Bound(c => c.opYear).Width(100);
                     columns.Bound(c => c.opPeriod).Width(100);
                     columns.Bound(c => c.val).Width(100)
                                  .ClientTemplate(@Html.ActionLink("#=val#", "myAction", "myController", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new{ para1 = @ViewBag.para1, para2 = "#=opYear#", para3 = "#=opPeriod#",@class = "postLink k-button", onclick = "myFunction(this)" })
                                  .ToHtmlString());             

                 }
    .
    .
    )

    <script>
        function myFunction(e) {
             var _para1 = $(e).attr("para1");
             var _para2 = $(e).attr("para2");
             var _para3 = $(e).attr("para3");
             var parameters = { param1: _para1, param2: _para2, param3: _para3 };
             $.Ajax({
                     method: 'POST',
                     url: $(e).attr("href"),
                     data: parameters,
                     success: function (success) 
                                       {
                                       alert(success);
                                       }
                   });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: You cannot 'hide' route values. Just POST the values rather than adding them as route values to the url (add the values as `data-*` attributes so that they can be retrieved in the click handler)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Thank you for your help, I have updated the question, but my Post is not working. It sends a Get to the Controller?

Comment: You have  not cancelled the default action of your link, so you making a GET and a the ajax POST

Comment: Just change the html to `<a href="#" class="postLink k-button" data-para1="@ViewBag.para1" data-para2=...` etc and then the script is `$('.postLink').click(function() { $.post('@Url.Action(yourActionName, yourControllerName)', { para1: $(this).data('para1), para1: $(this).data('para2), etc }, function(response) { // do something }`

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, Thanks, POST now is working as per your suggestion, all parameters are going to the Post action in the controller, I will update my post with the solution in a couple of days.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke,  I have a small issue, I checked in debug, and I can see  my view is being processed with data sent from the controller, but nothing is being rendered?

Comment: What do you mean _but nothing is rendered_? What are you expecting to happen. Where is you code that renders something? You have nothing inside the success callback.